# Integrating a Processing Sketch (PApplet) with javaFX GUI (From GUI Builder 2.0)

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, javafx, processing

I have been experimenting with integrating a PApplet with a JavaFX GUI designed in the GUI builder (2.0). After creating a SwingNode and adding my sketch instance to it, it fails to update its frame after drawing once.

I have minimal experience with JavaFX and and coming from using Swing, I have no idea how to access the components I have placed in the GUI builder outside of the **FXMLDocumentController** class. 
I am assuming the sketch would need to be initialised from the **JFXP** class but I do not know how to access the content of the SwingNode. 
Ideally I would want to be able to use the scene builder[2.0] to create the GUI rather than creating the components non-visually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

FXML Controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import processing.core.*;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    mySketch p = new mySketch();
    @FXML
    public Label label;
    public SwingNode sn;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(p);
        p.init();
        sn.setContent(panel);

    }

    static class mySketch extends PApplet {

        int x, y;

        @Override
        public void setup() {
            smooth();
            size(500, 200);
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            loop();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw() {
            background(255);
            x = x + randInt(0, 5);
            y = y + randInt(0, 5);
            ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 5);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved() {

        }
    }

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
        // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
        Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.embed.swing.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="papplettest.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <SwingNode fx:id="sn" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="100.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author hugodarwood
 */
public class JFXP extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
After a lot of research (and designing far too many applications in Swing) I have concluded that it is **not** possible to integrate a PApplet with a JAVAFX GUI. The best course of action is either to stick with Swing (not possible as of Processing 3.0) or learn graphical programming with JAVAFX.

**Hope is not lost!** there is a very dirty workaround for this. Simply write your sketch using processing.js, embed it in an HTML canvas and then add a JAVAFX WebView component to your project setting your HTML canvas as the WebEngine target. This way it is possible to keep using your existing processing sketches with a fancy JAVAFX UI!

Comment: What version of Processing are you using? As of 3.0, you can no longer embed a PApplet in a Java application.

Comment: 2.2.1 stable. It just seems strange given how readily it works with swing frontends... Swing seems vastly outdated though

Comment: Similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709779/java-processing-3-paplet-in-javafx-scene-as-fxnode/52782409#52782409).